# Confusion with Notation - What does $t = s0$ or $t=s1$ mean?

Tags: notation

Reference: Blackburn, Modal Logic, Section 1.3, Ex 1.3.2:

$B$ is a set of strings of $0$s and $1$s, and $R_1,R_2$ are two relations defined on $B$ by (i) $sR_1t$ iff $t=s0$ or $t=s1$ (ii) $sR_2t$ iff $t$ is a proper initial segment of $s$.

What does the notation $s0$ and $s1$ mean? I couldn't find this in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t$ and $s$ are bit strings.  $s0$ is the bit string $s$ with an extra 0 bit appended.  $s1$ is the bit string $s$ with an extra 1 bit appended.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Is this standard notation?

Comment: I've seen this kind of notation used many times for bit strings.